# URL to code in node.js applications

Tags: node.js, rest, url, request

I see they use this kind of code to call restful URLs.
Let's say we have /users/{userId}/tasks to create task for a user.

To call this they create another class instead of calling [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) directly as shown below:

```
MyAPP.prototype.users = function (userId) {

      return {
           tasks:  function (taskId) {
              return this.usersTasks(userId, taskId);
           }
      }
}

MyAPP.prototype.usersTasks = function (userId, taskId) {

        return {
            create: function (task, cb) {
                make request POST call
            }
        }
}
```

Then we can call this as `myapp.users('123').tasks().create(task, cb);`

What is this kind of coding called and is there any way to automatically generate the code from the URL structure itself?

Comment: has my answer been of any help? :)

Answer (score 0):

That is a way of making classes, but I suggest you look into [ES6 classes](http://2ality.com/2015/02/es6-classes-final.html)

Defining a class :

```
class MyAPP {
  //:called when created
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    console.log("[created] MyAPP :",name);
    //(a in memory database stored in MyAPP : for example purpose)
    this.DB = {'user000':{'tasks':{'task000':'do pizza'},{'task001':'code some magik'}}}
  }
  //: Get specific taskID for userID
  getTask(userID, taskID) {
     console.log("[get task]",taskID,"[from user]",userID)
     return (this.DB[userID][taskID])
  }
  //: Get all tasks for userID
  allTasks(userID) {
     console.log("[get all tasks from user]",userID)
     return (this.DB[userID].tasks)
  }
  //: Create a taskID with taskContent for userID
  newTask(userID, taskID, taskContent) {
     this.DB[userID].tasks[taskID] = taskContent
  }
}
```

Creating a MyAPP instance :

```
var myapp = new MyAPP('Pizza API'); //creates a MyAPP with a name
```

And then (maybe I got your question wrong) using `express` you would make a server and listen for requests (GET, POST, PUT, ...)

```
app.get("/APIv1/:userID/:actionID", function(req, res) {
  switch(req.params.actionID){
    case 'all':
       res.send(myapp.allTasks(req.params.userID)); 
       break
    default : 
       res.send("The "+myapp.name+" doesn't support that (yet)")
       break
  }
});
```